# Nodejs Safe MQTT Connection

Tags: node.js, ssl, mqtt

On my server I'm using a node.js based mqtt broker (mosca) which has an SSL Certificate from Certbot.

On the client side, I'm using a node.js based solution as well (mqtt.js)

Now my question is: In order to have a safe connection, do I need to have the property `rejectUnauthorized: true`? Because I can only get it to work when having a self signed certificate, which of course isn't very secure. When having a regular SSL cert on server-side i can't get it to work having `rejectUnauthorized: true`, why?

My server options:

```
const settings = {
  port: 8883, 
  secure: {
    keyPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/privkey.pem',
    certPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/cert.pem',
  },
  https: {
    port: 443,
    bundle: true,
    static: './',
  },
};
```

My connection options on client side:

```
const options = {
  host: "XXXXXX",
  port: 8883,
  protocol: "mqtts",
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  username: process.env.USERNAME,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
};
```

Error im receiving:

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1318:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:792:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:606:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the error when you don't use the `rejectUnauthorized: true` in the client settings. Also include the version of NodeJS you are using.

Comment: I would start checking if the fqdn on the regular cert matches the one on your server, also if you can post any error messages that you receive will definitively help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your server side settings to point to the `fullchain.pem` rather than the `cert.pem` file

This will include the full trust chain in what the server presents which should then include the root CA cert that will be in the trusted set that is baked into NodeJS.